# Not able to build SQL Server project with "AT TIME ZONE" in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, timezone, sql-server-2016, utc

Query with AT TIME ZONE executed as expected in SQL Server 2016. But if I am adding  same query in SQL Server project of Visual Studio 2015, I get a build error

> Incorrect Syntax near "AT TIME ZONE".

Code:

```
DECLARE @Result DATETIME
DECLARE @InputDate DATETIME
        @TimeZone NVARCHAR(50)    

SET @Result = @InputDate AT TIME ZONE @TimeZone AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AT TIME ZONE APPLIES TO:

- SQL Server (starting with 2016)
- Azure SQL Database

ONLY.

Change your **sql server project** type to SQL Server 2016 (or Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12).

Comment: AT TIME ZONE is supported in Azure SQL Database, but when you switch your project target to Azure, it fails to compile. 2016+ work, but then you can't deploy to Azure. Any suggestions?